# Rails Nested Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, subquery

I have follow query

```
  notes = Note.where('notes.id IN
  (
    SELECT "notes"."id" FROM "notes" 
      WHERE "notes"."circle_id" = ?
  )
  OR notes.id IN 
  (
    SELECT "notes"."id" FROM "notes" 
      INNER JOIN "circles_dreams" 
      ON "circles_dreams"."dream_id" = "notes"."dream_id" 
      WHERE "circles_dreams"."circle_id" = ? 
  )', @circle.id, @circle.id)
```

How to simplify this query? 
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can collect all needed notes id.
I supposed to think what you already have relations between `Note` and `CirclesDream`

```
note_ids = Note.where(circle_id: @circle.id).pluck(:id) # your first SELECT
dream_ids = CirclesDream.where(id: @circle.id).pluck(:note_id) # your second SELECT

notes_ids = note_ids | dreams_ids # combine them

notes = Note.where(id: notes_ids) # Now your
```

**upd:** I've just fixed typo. Changed `id` to `note_id` in second request

Comment: @lito `> [1, 2, 3] | [1, 4, 5] # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
note_ids = Note.where('circle_id = ?', @circle.id).pluck(:id)

dream_note_ids = Note.joins(:circle_dreams).where('circle_dreams.circle_id = ?', @circle.id).plunk(:note_id)

notes_ids = note_ids | dream_note_ids
```

If your `circle_dreams` table can contain records having `note_id = null`, then you have to apply join. So i think this will work in your case....